# Group files into lists according to their date in the filename using Python

Tags: python, regex, string, datetime, parsing

I have several files in a directory. In all of these filenames are the dates "hidden". For example a little excerpt looks like this:

```
HLS.S30.T34JDN.2018301.v1.4.hdf
HLS.S30.T34JEN.2018308.v1.4.hdf
HLS.S30.T34JDN.2018311.v1.4.hdf      
HLS.S30.T34JEP.2018293.v1.4.hdf
```

The date is the Julian Day of the Year. In this case it's 301, 308, 311 and 293. In the directory are files which have the same day and I want to group them together into separate lists using `Python`.

I think this isn't too hard, but I don't know too much about parsing(?)/regex.

Comment: Why do you need regex? `line.split('.')[3][4:]` does it

Comment: Awesome!! Thank a lot! Can you maybe explain to me in words what happening there?

Answer (score 1):

Using the `os.listdir()` method ([documentation here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html)), you can get a list of all the filenames as strings, then use string comprehension to pull out the date. Eg:

```
for filename in os.listdir(path):
    year = int(filename[15:19])
    day = int(filename[19:22])
    # then sort as needed, eg:
    lst.append(path+filename)
    # Using path+filename gives the full path to the file needed,
    # whereas filename is just the name of the file as a string.
```